# jQuery.ajax() and XML validation

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, validation

So I'm trying to do this thing where *XML* is obtained through *AJAX* and passed on to a function. Now, I don't know anything about **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML** apart from a small `jQuery.ajax()` tutorial I read somewhere on the internet. All I know is that *AJAX* gets the *XML* for me and provides me a callback function by the name of `success` as a property of `ajaxSettings`, where I can process XML data - it's relevant - *using jQuery functions*.

So, here's a possible scenario.

```
// Inside $.ready()...
$.ajax({
   type:     'GET',
   dataType: 'xml',
   url:      'res/xml/data.xml',
   success:  function(xmlDoc) {
      $('#elements').processData(xmlDoc); // In scope, of course...
   }
});
```

Now, here is the function that I called inside `success(xmlDoc)`

```
$.fn.processData = function(args) {
   // TODO: ________
}
```

**TODO:** Check if args is valid XML. Now, as I mentioned before, `xmlDoc` can be processed using jQuery functions, which means it's already a jQuery object, which means that jQuery (or `jQuery.ajax`) has already made sure it's valid XML, *or does it?* If it doesn't, how do I make sure it's valid XML, or at least just XML?

I have a couple of other **off-topic** things to mention and/or ask here.

1. Is it a good idea to extend `$.fn` even if I'm not developing a proper plugin?
2. Most jQuery functions are overloaded, e.g. `$('#toTheseElements').doSomething( withTheseArgs )` works just as well as `$.doSomething( $('#toTheseElements'), withTheseArgs )`. How do they do that? And is it a good thing? And how would I go about it if I wanted to do that? I looked over the internet and found many solutions but most of them are just hacks. Is there an optimal (and elegant) solution?
3. What if I wanted to add other securities to `processData(args)`? For example, check if the elements on which `processData(args)` has been called are *(all)* elements of a certain type? I know about `$.is('elementType')` but that returns true even if just one of the elements of the `elementType` type. I could `$.each()` but I cannot `return` if I encounter an element which is not of `elementType` type.
4. AJAX being asynchronous, is it safe to use `xmlDoc` as an argument to another function inside the `success()` function? I don't know much about sync or async functions, but I encountered another async function a few days ago and kept wondering why it kept returning empty variables *and ended up making a fool of myself on the internet... So, should I fear async?

The *off-topic* questions are genuinely off-topic, so that means you may choose to ignore them and I wouldn't mind at all. Cheerio!

Comment: I'm not sure that jQuery does any sort of validation on the xml ahead of time, but if you just pass it a selector and check the length, you'll get zero if the corresponding node isn't there. That is, if your xml is supposed to have a < Foo > tag in it, then you should find that $('Foo', xml).length !== 0. I'm pretty sure that jQuery will not give you anything good if the xml is bad.

Comment: Thank you @GreatBigBore. That is actually one of the solutions I came across on the interwebs... In fact, this is the one I am using right now. But as I mentioned, it's more of a hack than a solution. Although in my *limited* experience, many of the genuine solutions are actually obfuscated hacks. Still, I'd like to leave this question open. Maybe someone comes up with a better one. Cheers!